# Android App question: special phone list

Tags: android, contacts

I am trying to write an app that will allow the user to select from a list of contacts to make a list of contacts that if a call is received from in a range of hours will have a selectable ringtone different from what it would be normally.
For example the user could select the numbers of a group of their friends and if a call was received from any of them between the hours of midnight to 5 AM the phone would use the alternate ringtone.
I'm pretty inexperienced and so have pretty much no idea how to access the contacts list or replace the ringtone. Any help would be appreciated